# How do I count the number of paragraphs in a SQL text column?

Tags: sql-server, varchar

I have a column called `description` with a datatype of `varchar(MAX)`.

I would like to know how many paragraphs are in each description. How could I do this? I have tried:

```
select
    len(description) - len(REPLACE(description, '\n', '')) as numParagraphs
```

but it keeps returning 0 paragraphs. Any advice?

I realized a way to do it...

```
select len(description) - len(replace(REPLACE(description, '.<br/>', 
''),'. <br/>','')),
```

Not perfect due to spacing but almost there. For some reason our delimiters are `<br/>`

Comment: Do you have a sample data? also with the sample output.

Comment: try `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)`

Comment: @reds I think sample data in this case will be altered by posting on SO to be unrepresentative of what is actually in the db

Comment: @Brad just a dummy data i think it's enough.

Comment: @artm, I think it should be 13+10, not 10+13

Comment: @TKL, is your text XML, HMTL or normal text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to count paragraphs, you already know. You seem to be looking for possibilities of what constitutes a new paragraph, yet you don't want to or cannot examine your data in its natural output habitat.

Oh well, possibilities game started:

- `'\n'`
- `'\r'`
- `'\r\n'`
- `'<br/>'`
- `CHAR(13)`
- `CHAR(10)`
- `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`

Comment: Barely know about wikis but hopefully I made a correct call for this.